# I want to annotate my data based on (refined) named entity that I extracted by spaCy

Tags: regex, python-3.x, annotations

I have worked on around 7000 sentences with Spacy in order to extract Named Entity. I extracted :
Long, Date, Star, Para, Astr, Plan, Names AS entity.  As you see here in the link:

https://ibb.co/rtQm5B9

Now I want to (assign) annotate each sentence to

"observation" or "not observation" label 1 and 0

based on the Named entity that I provided. I have gathered my data in the panda data frame and I add the entity tuples
 (text, type entity) like this (2h 14m, Date). Sometimes there is more than one entity in one sentences

The problem is I don't know how can I have access to tuples in each row and how can I define a new column based on the entity in each column.

My data look like this: (python dataframe)

https://ibb.co/vdfXJFD

[image: tail of data]

how can I make new column based on the entity column, for instance, if there is the entity (second element in each tuple in the column enitites) with label data and long, then we can assign to new column label 1 and if not we can assign label 0

Comment: Your link to https://ufile.io/8eppssug doesn't seem to work. Please fix it so that people can help you.

Comment: I edit that one, tnx for comment

Comment: Is there some code which would show your research effort to this problem.If so kindly post it.

Comment: @mishsx you have the code in below

Answer (score 0):

I solved it somehow:

```
def annot_observation_01(x):
    y=0
    if x is not None:
        for idx in range(0,len(x)):
                    if any ([x[idx][1] == 'LONG', x[idx][1] == 'DATE']):
                        y=1
                    else:
                        y=0   
    else:
        y=0
    return y
```

then I add it to my dataframe like this:

```
dfAstroNova['label'] = dfAstroNova['entities'].apply(lambda x: annot_observation_01(x))
```

[image]

As you see in the code, it says if the label in entities is "LONG" or "DATE" it gives value 1 TO column label, how can I write my function if it gives value 1 when both of labels "LONG" and "DATE" appears in sentences?